# Excel workbook using user defined functions always produces "save" prompt when closing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

*** Replacement for original posting. ***

After following the suggestions made in this thread, 
and some others that I found using Google,
I realised that I had made a mistake in the original posting.

After a good night's sleep, I decided to start again.

I am trying to create an Excel VBA function to remove trailing spaces from a character string.
This is my function code.

```
Function TrimTrailing(Text As String) As String
   TrimTrailing = RTrim(Text)
End Function
```

I am using Excel 2019, Version 2002 (Build 12527.20278 Click-to-Run).
In each case, the Workbook Calculation option is set to Automatic.

**Step One**

I created a macro-enabled workbook called `DEMO00M.xlsm`.
This contained the function, renamed `TrimTrailing0`.
As a simple test, I keyed `A  B`, `=TrimTrailing0(A1)`, `=LEN(A1)` and `=LEN(B1)` into worksheet cells `A1` to `D1`.
This worked as expected.

**Step Two**

I used `DEMO00M.xlsm` to create an add-in file called `DEMO01A.xlam`.
This contained the function, renamed `TrimTrailing1`.
This file was stored in the `C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns` folder.
As a test, I created a standard workbook called `DEMO01X.xlsx`.
I used "File -> Options -> Add-ins" to activate the new add-in.
As a simple test, I keyed `A  B`, `=TrimTrailing1(A1)`, `=LEN(A1)` and `=LEN(B1)` into worksheet cells `A1` to `D1`.
The `TrimTrailing1` function worked as expected.
But whenever I closed the workbook, I received the prompt "Want to save changes to `DEMO01X.xlsx`?", even when I had made no changes.

Following a suggestion, I saved the workbook as a macro-enabled workbook called `DEMO01M.xlsm`. This did not make any difference.

**Step Three**

Following another suggestion, I created a `PERSONAL.XLSB` workbook containing the function (renamed `TrimTrailing2`).
This file was stored in the `C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` folder.
It is a "hidden" file that is opened whenever Excel is started.
As a test, I created a standard workbook called `DEMO02X.xlsx`.
I used "File -> Options -> Add-ins" to activate the new add-in.
I keyed `A  B`, `=PERSONAL.XLSB!TrimTrailing2(A1)`, `=LEN(A1)` and `=LEN(B1)` into worksheet cells `A1` to `D1`.
The `TrimTrailing2` function worked as expected, but I had the same "save at close" issue as before.

I also saved `DEMO02X.xlsx` as a macro-enabled workbook called `DEMO02M.xlsm`. This did not make any difference.

**Step Four**

Another option is to store the function in a macro-enabled workbook and access it from other workbooks. 
This is similar to using a `PERSONAL.XLSB` workbook, but in my opinion, much less convenient.
I created `DEMO03M.xlsm` workbook containing the function (renamed `TrimTrailing3`).
If `DEMO03M.xlsm` is open, the function can be accessed using a formula like `=DEMO03M.xlsm!TrimTrailing3(A1)`.
The `TrimTrailing3` function worked as expected, but I had the same "save at close" issue as before.

**Step Five**

I created a workbook called `DEMO01M-WO.xlsm` from the `DEMO01M.xlsm` workbook.
I added this sub routine to the ThisWorkbook object.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

This runs when the workbook has been opened and resets the "dirty" state of the workbook,
so that it will not need to be saved before closing, unless a subsequent change is made.
When I first tried this approach, it did not work, for some reason.
I think I must have made a mistake, because it now worked appears to work perfectly.
The "save at close" issue has been avoided.

I did more tests with this work around.
I created `DEMO02M-WO.xlsm` from `DEMO02M.xlsm` and `DEMO03M-WO.xlsm` from `DEMO03M.xlsm`.
These workbooks behave correctly and the "save at close" issue has been avoided.

It seems that when a user defined function is declared in a separate workbook, it is treated as volatile. Could this be a bug?

My knowledge of VBA is a bit thin, have I coded the function incorrectly?

The ideal situation would be to able to store functions in an add-in workbook,
so that they are available to all standard workbooks in a the same way as the built-in functions.

I have done some tests using another with PC which has Excel 2013 (15.0.5223.1001).
It appears to have the same problem.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if the file is **.xlsm** instead of **.xlsx** ??

Comment: Just tried that. Same result. But if I store a function in a .XLSM file the save prompt is not used. Converting to an .XLAM file seems to cause the problem.

Comment: Doesn't directly address your question, but consider putting the UDF in the "Personal.xlsb" file

Comment: Just tried using a Personal.xlsb file. Not sure if I used the right method. In the workbook I had to code =Personal.xlsb!TrimTrailing(a2) . Unfortunately the save prompt is still made each time the workbook is closed.